# Getting WCF "ServiceModel" Security Negotiation Exception: SOAP security negotiation with for target failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating WCF with security settings and l keep getting below error:
" Security Negotiation Exception: SOAP security negotiation with for target  failed"

this is my web.config code:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://10.21.101.3/ws/RRS/PeInfo/EXT/CF01"
        behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="ncsiCustomB"
        contract="rot.PersonInformation_WSSP_ASE_PortType" name="rotservicedemo">
        <identity>
          <dns value="ROT ESB Msg Signature Stg" />
          
        </identity>
       
      </endpoint>
    </client>
```